# Compare letter in java

Tags: java, compare

I want to compare every letter on file 2 with file 1. 
example :

> file 1 : my name
>   file 2 : mi n@mes

i want to get the number of difference is 3, on file 2 : (i, @,and s).
Can you help me

Here is my code

```
public float getCER(String originalteks,String extractteks){
    int end=0;
    int start=0;
    int different_char=0;

    if(originalteks.length()!=extractteks.length()){
        different_char=Math.abs(originalteks.length()-extractteks.length());
    }
    while(start<end){
        if(originalteks.charAt(start)!=originalteks.charAt(start++))
            different_char++;//jumlah diferent chart
    }

    return (float) different_char/originalteks.length();


}
```

And it's only counting the number of characters, not the different characters.

Comment: Are the files guaranteed to have the same number of characters? If not, how do you want to deal with insertions or deletions of characters? Are you just interested in differences by position? Do you want something like the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? If so, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41515082/535871).

Comment: shouldn't you initialize `end` ? from this code, `end` is always 0 and thus `while(start<end)` won't run...

Comment: if you are counting letters, why is the method returning float? is it possible to count half a letter?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I just comment my changes within the example.

```
public int getCER(String originalteks,String extractteks){
  int end;
  int different_char=0;

  //define the shorter end
  if(originalteks.length < extractteks.length)
    end = originalteks.length();
  else
    end = extractteks.length();

  //no if needed -> same length, diff will be 0
  different_char=Math.abs(originalteks.length()-extractteks.length());

  for(int start = 0; start < end; start++){
      if(originalteks.charAt(start)!=extractteks.charAt(start))
          different_char++;//jumlah diferent chart
  }

  return different_char;
}
```

Comment: okay. but it's only compare the number of charachter. the question is how to compare and count different charachters base on file 1. 
example : 
file 1 : "question"
file 2 " "kuestiom".
the number of different letter compared by file1 is 2, on "k,m"

Comment: Ok, i fixed this problem. Now you get the number of different chars.

Answer (score 0):

The following implementation tests for the total difference you need and is able to handle strings with different length, by comparing the shorter string to each substring of the longer up to the maximum offset of their difference. From those differences the smallest is chosen. Of course, if handleOffset is false, then we limit ourselves to only the start of the string and adding the difference to the result;

```
public int getCER(String originalteks,String extractteks, boolean handleOffset){
    String shorter = originalteks;
    String longer = extractteks;
    if (shorter.length() > longer.length()) {
        shorter = extractteks;
        longer = originalteks;
    }
    int[] differences = new int[handleOffset ? (longer.length() - shorter.length + 1) : 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < differences.length; i++) differences[i] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < differences.length; j++) {
            if (shorter.charAt(i) !== longer.charAt(i + j)) {
                differences[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
    int min = shorter.length() + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < differences.length; i++) {
        if (differences[i] < min) min = differences[i];
    }
    if (!handleOffset) min += longer.length() - shorter.length();
    return min;
}
```